# Error "User does not have sufficient permissions error for Google Analytics"

Tags: c#-4.0, google-analytics-api

Sometimes I get this error while pulling data from Google Analytics.

```
"code":403,"message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."
```

This error occurs only for some profile IDs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you be more accurate on how you *pull data* and how often you get the error? How is your question related to C#?

Comment: I have written method in c# application to call Google analytics api to fetch data according to refresh token and profile ID, for some user's data its showing above defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you are authenticating with must have access to the profile id you are trying to request data from.

> 403
>     [insufficientPermissions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors)    
>  Indicates that the user does not
>   have sufficient permissions for the entity specified in the query.    Do
>   not retry without fixing the problem. You need to get sufficient
>   permissions to perform the operation on the specified entity.

I would check your code or have it write out the profile id that is causing you a problem. You may have mistyped it.

Note: You can also get this error if the user's access in Google analytics was removed.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to add one note here  I tried by regenerated profile ID for that user and newly generated profile Id was different from previous one. Now its fetching data with newly generated profile Id.

Comment: At least it wasn't like my problem once with a dyslexic moment took two hours to see it :/